# Multiples databases en una query en laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, php7

llevo poco en el mundo de laravel y necesito para mi trabajo hacer algo como esto:

```
$results = DB::select('select * from database1.users u1 LEFT JOIN database2.users u2 ON u1.id = u2.id WHERE u2.id = ?', array(5));
```

La pregunta es como configuro el config/database.php y el .env. Ya que hay diferentes bases de datos en una sola query, agradecería algún tips sobre esto.

Saludos.

Comment: Estas utilizando laravel Query Builder o la opción ORM?

Comment: laravel Query Builder, las bases de datos están en SQL Server, saludos.

Comment: como digo, soy nuevo en laravel, no se que poner en el .env ni en el database.php en config, para que pueda hacer una query que consulte 3 bases de datos, hasta ahora he trabajado solo con una base de datos con eloquent, saludos.

Comment: ¿Donde se coloca esto?:  "mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1/forge?charset=UTF-8"

Comment: Aquí www.laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#introduction sale eso, supongo que será una conexión similar pero de SQL Server.